# C program Temperature conversion

Tags: c

Can anyone please explain what am i doing wrong here? It seems whatever is under ***if*** is not being executed. but i don't understand why.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{   float Fah, Cel, Temp;
    char  scale,F,C;
    printf("Press F to convert to fahrenheit\n");
    printf("Press C to convert in celcius\n");
    scanf("%c",&scale);

    if(scale==C)
    { 
      printf("Enter the temp\n");

      scanf("%f",&Fah);  
      Temp=(Fah-32)/1.8;
    }
    else
    {
     if(scale==F)
     {
       printf("Enter the temp\n");

       scanf("%f",&Cel);
       Temp=(Cel*1.8)+32;
     }
    } 
    printf("The temperature  is %f\n",Temp);
    getch();
}
```

Output:

```
Press F to convert to fahrenheit
Press C to convert in celcius
C
The temperature  is 0.000000
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `if (scale == C)` -> `if (scale == 'C')`

Comment: `C` and `F` are non initialized `char` variables, so they contain garbage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has several issues:

#### 1.

Your approach is incorrect.

You need to use `if (scale == 'C')` instead of `if (scale == C)` and `if (scale == 'f')` instead of `if (scale == F)` and omit the definition of `C` and `F` as `char` variables.

`'C'` is a character constant.

`C` is, in your case, a uninitialized `char` variable. It does not contain any specified value. Thus, the behavior of the program is [undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Same goes for `F`.

---

#### 2.

You should have an `else` statement after `if (scale == 'C')` and `else if (scale == 'F')` which covers the case when the input provided is different than `'C'` or `'F'` (you will never know what the user may input).

---

#### 3.

Furthermore, since `scanf()` leaves a trailing newline character back in `stdin` - Made by the press to <kbd>Enter</kbd> - you need to catch this newline character by f.e. `getchar()` following each `scanf()` statement to not skip the following input operation.

---

#### 4.

`main()` is not correct. Use at least `int main()`, or even better `int main (void)` to be standard-compliant.

---

#### 5.

`getch()` isn´t part of `stdio.h` and even the C standard library in general. It is either a function from `conio.h` (Windows/MS-DOS) or the ncurses-library (Linux). Thus, you need to include the specific header.

Probably it was a typo and you meant `getchar()` instead, but worth to hint.

---

Side note:

You should always check the return value of `scanf()` if the input was successfullly consumed.

---

Result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{   
    float Fah, Cel, Temp;
    char scale;
    printf("Press F to convert to fahrenheit\n");
    printf("Press C to convert in celcius\n");
    scanf("%c", &scale);
    getchar();

    if (scale == 'C')   
    { 
        printf("Enter the temp\n");

        if (scanf("%f", &Fah) != 1)
        {
             fputs("Wrong Input!", stderr);
             return 1;
        } 
        getchar();                  // For catching newline character.
 
        Temp = (Fah-32) / 1.8;
    }

    else if (scale == 'F')
    {
        printf("Enter the temp\n");

        if (scanf("%f", &Cel) != 1)
        {
            fputs("Wrong Input!", stderr);
             return 1;
        } 
        getchar();                   // For catching newline character.

        Temp = (Cel * 1.8) + 32;
    }

        else 
        {
               // Case for different input than 'F' and 'C'.
               // Probably Error routine.
               printf("Wrong input!\n");
        }

    printf("The temperature  is %f\n", Temp);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for such a descriptive answer. I'm trying to grasp everything you've pointed out. So, my first question is- I've declared the variable ***scale*** to have ***char*** data type. And i thought ***scanf*** should hold the character ***C*** or ***F*** as typed by the user as i have defined it as such. Then why is it necessary   to use *** if (scale == 'C')*** instead of just  ***if (scale == C)***

Comment: @adi99 `C`, as you used it, is a variable of type `char`. This `C` is just a name for a variable, but no character *value* itself. To proof if `scale` contains the *value* of the character `C` we need to compare it to a proper character (value), not a variable. To confuse you even more imagine the following: `char C = 'C'`;` - This defines C as a `char` variable and assigns the actual value of the character C to the variable called C. In this way you could even use `if (scale == C)` as the variable C holds now the *value* of the C character.

Comment: @adi99 - But we don´t need to use a variable called C to hold the C character value here. We can just compare `scale` by the actual character value itself. For doing so, we need to surround the C by `'` -> `'C'` to make it a so called "*character constant*".

Comment: I apologize but i still have query. While I do get your point as to why declaring ***C*** and ***F*** as ***char*** is unnecessary but what I'm having trouble with is this part  ```scanf("%c",&scale); if(scale=='C') ``` When i rewrite my code removing ***F*** and ***C*** from char making it ```float Fah, Cel, Temp; char  scale;``` and keep the ***if*** section as ```if(scale==C)``` i'll get an error saying ***C*** is not declared. But it works when its written as ```if(scale=='C')```. Can u plz explain why

Comment: . Besides in ur comment earlier u wrote  ```char C = 'C'```; i'd like u to explain how is it different from ```char C = C```.

Comment: @adi99 Pop quiz. - If you use `if (scale == C)` what do you think is `C` here? Re-Read my first comment.

Comment: @adi99 If you use `if (scale == C)`, `C` is a variable. If you remove the declaration of the variable `C`, the compiler will throw an error.

Comment: @adi99 Furthermore: What do you think is the right `C` here -> `char C = C`? Is it a character value or just the variable `C`?